# Why is .net core identity external login not prompting to select user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have setup the scaffolded `.Net core identity` with external logins using **facebook** and **google**. The login works fine, but when a user logs out, then wants to log back in using **google** or **facebook**, they don't get prompted to select **WHICH** user account to use from google or facebook. It just automatically signs them in with the account they last used on the computer.

My guess is that some cookies does not get cleared when they log out. Any ideas what is happening and how to fix it?

Setup for `login`:

```
services
.AddAuthentication(o = >
{
    o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
.AddGoogle(options => {})
.AddFacebook(optionz =>{})
.AddIdentityCookies(o = >{});
```

Im using the standard scaffolded AccountController from microsoft for `login`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null) 
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    _logger.LogInformation($ "Loggin using {provider}");
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", 
    new 
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl
    });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

And `Logout` is:

```
[HttpGet]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task <IActionResult> LogOff() 
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation(4, "User logged out.");
    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

Comment: maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51812687/9936356

Comment: I think the `SignOutAsync` method should delete cookies,I am not sure where your problem lies, but I think it may be related to your authentication scheme. You can try to use Cookie authentication scheme.

Comment: A weird thing is the correlation cookie is not deleted upon logout